# Second mutable borrow error with only one mutable borrow

Tags: rust

This doesn't make much sense because it returns the same thing regardless of the `if let`, but it is a concise example of the problem that I am running into:

```
struct Data {
    value: Option<i32>,
}

impl Data {
    fn get(&mut self) -> Option<&mut i32> {
        if let Some(val) = &mut self.value {
            return Some(val);
        }

        return self.value.as_mut();
    }
}
```

This code produces the error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.value` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:11:16
   |
6  |     fn get(&mut self) -> Option<&mut i32> {
   |            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
7  |         if let Some(val) = &mut self.value {
   |                            --------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
8  |             return Some(val);
   |                    --------- returning this value requires that `self.value` is borrowed for `'1`
...
11 |         return self.value.as_mut();
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I don't understand why this is a second mutable borrow when the first one goes out of scope before the second one will ever occur.

The `val` variable is not in scope after the `if let`, so how is this a second borrow? The first borrow should have already been released.

Just to be completely sure, I even surrounded the `if let` with another block:

```
{
    if let Some(val) = &mut self.value {
        return Some(val);
    }
}

return self.value.as_mut();
```

This produced the same error. What is going on here?

Comment: maybe it's more clear with https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7765d0286fae5d7bcc07cef9ab593884

Comment: By the way, it's not idiomatic Rust to use explicit `return` at the end of a block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lifetime of `'a` encompasses the entire function body because the return value needs to borrow `self`. Hence, the first borrow's scope extends past the if expression and into the entire function body.

Non Lexical Lifetimes were intended to fix this [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21906) by reducing the scope of the first borrow to only include the if expression. You can see this in effect by moving the borrowed value into a local variable [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=d56b7e45e1deca53b341b52405b215eb):

```rs
fn get(&mut self) -> Option<&mut i32> {
    let value = &mut self.value;
    if let Some(val) = value {
        return Some(val);
    }
    return value.as_mut();
}
```

However, the support for conditionally returning values was [removed](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/06/15/mir-based-borrow-check-nll-status-update/) because it took too much compilation time. This feature is still being worked on and can be enabled with the `-Zpolonius` flag:
`RUSTFLAGS="-Zpolonius" cargo +nightly build`

With which, the original code compiles fine.